# WebClient.DownloadString() makes my application freeze during the "download" of the source code

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm trying to have my application download the source code of a website and filter out the information that I need to pull on my application.

Everything is fine and dandy however the UI freezes until my application finishes downloading the source code of the site.

If there is **anywhere** I can get help, this has got to be the place. :)

Here's the code that makes me cry:

```
public void LoadPlayersOnline()
    {
        WebClient WebClientClass = new WebClient();

        string SiteSource = WebClientClass.DownloadString("http://forums.chronic-domination.com/");
        int AlliancePos = SiteSource.IndexOf("Alliance");
        string AlliancePlayers = SiteSource.Substring((AlliancePos + 14), 3);

        label5.Text = AlliancePlayers;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will most likely want to use DownloadStringAsync. Then implement the events on it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient_events(VS.80).aspx DownloadCompleted.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync(VS.80).aspx

Comment: After reading the link provided I can't seem to figure out how to use the "DownloadStringCallback"? What is that? Thanks for the help.

Comment: DownloadStringCallback can be any call back method that has an argument of  DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs

public static void DownloadStringCallback2 (Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    // If the request was not canceled and did not throw
    // an exception, display the resource.
    if (!args.Cancelled && args.Error == null)
    {
        string textString = (string)args.Result;

        Console.WriteLine (textString);
    }
}

Comment: Bad stack overflow... Just check out the example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.downloadstringcompletedeventargs(VS.80).aspx